# determine $\left(\sum\limits_{g=1}^{p-1} g \times ((ag \mod p))\right) \bmod p^2$

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $((x))$ be the least positive residue of $x$ modulo $p$. For $a \in \{1, 2, ..., p-1\}$, consider $f(a) = \sum\limits_{g=1}^{p-1} g \times ((a g))$.

Does the following hold: $f(a)=f(b)$ if and only if $a=b$ or $a=b^{-1} \bmod p$？ Furthermore, can we determine $f(a) \bmod p^2$？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Edited again to account for G.Myerson's answer and fan's comments*]

It seems I can't delete even my own answers here, so I'm doing the next best thing:

Please ignore what I wrote in the first edit, ending with

> In particular the answer to the question as posed is "no".
>
> This assumes I computed what the proposer intended with the following **gp** code:

```
f(p, a) = sum(g=1,p-1,g*(a*g)%p)
```

That code is missing a pair of parentheses and should say

```
f(p, a) = sum(g=1,p-1,g*((a*g)%p)) a
```

With this correction, the answer is **yes**.  Experimental evidence through $p=199$ is consistent with the conjecture
$$
f(a) \equiv p \frac{a+a'}{12} \bmod p^2
$$
where $a'$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a \bmod p$, which would imply that $f(a)\equiv f(b) \bmod p^2$ iff $a \equiv b$ or $a \equiv b^{-1} \bmod p$, as desired.  In a previous edit I wrote at this point "I expect that (assuming I've not made yet another error) this corrected formula is known and/or not too hard to prove."  This expectation was confirmed a few hours later by the original proposer, building on an answer from Gerry Myerson, who wrote $f(a)$ in terms of a Dedekind sum:
$$
f(a) = p^2 \bigl(s(a,p) + \frac14(p-1)\bigr).
$$
To calculate $f(a) \bmod p^2$, we may ignore the term $p^2(p-1)/4$; the result then follows from the reciprocity formula for Dedekind sums:
$$
s(a,p) + s(p,a) = \frac{a^2-3ap+p^2+1}{12ap}
$$
together with the observation that the denominator of $s(p,a)$ is not a multiple of $p$.

Comment: Professor Elkies, the reason you are unable to delete your posts is that your account here is currently unregistered ([here are the general deletion rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222)). If you would like to put your most recent edit as a new answer, I can then delete this answer for you, if you would like.

Comment: Thanks so much! I comfirmed your formula following the suggestion of Gerry Myerson and by a known result involving Dedekind sum.

Comment: @Z.Chonoles: Thanks, but by now it's probably best to let the edited answer stand.  I'll register soon in case this happens again.  &fan: You're welcome; I saw the follow-ups by Myerson and you, and will edit my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

First,

> $f(a) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{g=1}^{p-1} [ (g + a(g))^2 - g^2 - a(g)^2 ] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_g (g + a(g))^2 - \sum_g g^2$ .

Next, note that $g + a(g) = c(g)$ or $c(g) + p$ for $a \neq p-1$, where $c = a+1 ($mod $p)$, and $g + a(g) = p$ for $a=p-1$.

So for $a=p-1$,

> $f(a) = \frac{p^2(p-1)}{2} - \frac{(p-1)p(2p-1)}{6} = \frac{(p-1)p(p+1)}{6}$.

For $a<p-1$,

> $f(a) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_g c(g)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{c(g)<g} (2c(g) p + p^2) - \frac{(p-1)p(2p-1)}{6} $
>   $ = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{c(g)<g} (2c(g) p + p^2) - \frac{(p-1)p(2p-1)}{12}$.

Now, I believe that for $c\neq 1$, $c(g)<g$ exactly half the time (as $c(-g) = p-c(g)$).  So we have in the latter case

> $ f(a) = \sum_{c(g)<g} c(g) p + \frac{p^2(p-1)}{4} - \frac{(p-1)p(2p-1)}{12} = \sum_{c(g)<g} c(g) p + \frac{(p-1)p(p+1)}{12}$.

**Edited:** That's as far as I got.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. However I think you might accidently make a mistake. $k*p<c*g<k*p+g$ iff $\frac{kp}{c}<g<\frac{kp}{c-1}$ other than $\frac{kp}{c} < g < \frac{kp}{c} + 1$ as you said.

Comment: Yes. Dumb mistake on my part.  I'll look at this later and see if I can salvage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but I can relate the question to [Dedekind sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_sum), for which there is a considerable literature (and I note that Noam Elkies suggested this in a comment at MathOverflow).

The least positive residue of $x$ modulo $p$ is given by $p\lbrace x/p\rbrace$, where the curly brackets indicate the fractional part. So $f(a)$, which I will write as $f(a,p)$, is given by $$f(a,p)=\sum_{g=1}^{p-1}gp\lbrace ag/p\rbrace=p\sum_{g=1}^{p-1}g\lbrace ag/p\rbrace$$

The Dedekind sum is given by $$s(h,k)=\sum_{\nu=1}^{k-1}\left({\nu\over k}-{1\over2}\right)\left(\left\lbrace{h\nu\over k}\right\rbrace-{1\over2}\right)$$ Multiplying out, $$s(h,k)=\sum_{\nu=1}^{k-1}{\nu\over k}\lbrace h\nu/k\rbrace+{\rm\ easy\ stuff}$$ that is, the other three sums are easy to evaluate (and are left as an exercise to the reader). So $$p^2s(a,p)=p\sum_{\nu=1}^{p-1}\nu\lbrace a\nu/p\rbrace+{\rm\ other\ easy\ stuff}$$ and thus $$f(a,p)=p^2s(a,p)+{\rm\ as\ usual}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I've figured out the answer following your steps. Actually $p^2s(a,p)$ mod $p^2$ is known to be $\frac{p(a^2+1)}{12a}$, and thus $f(a,p)$ mod $p^2$ is clear.